# Python: how to assign a dictionary a value which is a list with varying length?

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, matrix, scipy

I am trying to locate the centers of mass in a series of 100 2D `numpy` arrays like this:

```
array([[ 0.216,  0.24 ,  0.244, ...,  0.679,  0.684,  0.707],
       [ 0.23 ,  0.229,  0.238, ...,  0.675,  0.676,  0.695],
       [ 0.221,  0.238,  0.24 , ...,  0.669,  0.677,  0.684],
       ..., 
       [ 0.937,  0.925,  0.923, ...,  0.768,  0.754,  0.752],
       [ 0.937,  0.929,  0.923, ...,  0.737,  0.735,  0.741],
       [ 0.934,  0.932,  0.929, ...,  0.72 ,  0.717,  0.728]])
```

Based on a set of thresholds like this `cutoff_values=[0.05,0.1,0.2]`, I identify, for each matrix, the region of cells that satisfies `cell_value>=0.05`,`cell_value>=0.1` and `cell_value>=0.2`. Then, I compute the center of mass of each region (or group of cells).

This is to be executed 100 times. For each threshold there is a corresponding `dictionary` where I store the center of mass coordinates **in the form of a list**:

`dict005={'matrix 1':[row for center of mass, column for center of mass]}` for threshold=0.05

`dict01={...}` for threshold=0.1

`dict02={...}` for threshold=0.2

However, since each image might have multiple regions or group of cells where `cell_value>=0.05` (for instance), I will end up having lists which contain twice as much elements as centers of mass (each center of mass yields two values - its row and column).

**My question:** what needs be changed in my block (see below) to correctly fill the `dicts` I have just defined? **Basically, I am asking how it is possible to assign a dictionary a value which is a list of varying length.**

**Example**:
Cut-off=0.05

`dict005={'matrix 1':[17,29],'matrix 2':[23,45,88,101,234,432], 'matrix 3':[0,34,67,86]}`

Matrix 1 has 1 center of mass for values>0.05, matrix 2 has 3, matrix 3 has 2, and so forth until it reaches matrix 100.

**My block:**

```
dict005 = OrderedDict()
dict01 = OrderedDict()
dict02 = OrderedDict()

cutoff_values=[0.05, 0.1, 0.2] #A list containing all used cut-off values. 

for i, file in enumerate(os.listdir(directoryPath)):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):

       #The csv_to_matrix is computed here (my matrix of values)
        for val in enumerate(cutoff_values):

            if val == 0.05:
                # Relabels the matrix True or False based on the >= condition, val=0.05 being the first cut-off
                blobs = csv_to_matrix >= val 
                # Creates a few labels and records how many of them there are (nlabels)
                labels, nlabels = ndimage.label(blobs)
                # Empty list to store the coordinates row,column of the center of mass of each region
                list005 = []

                # loop through the nlabels identified
                for i in range(0, nlabels+1):
                    # compute row, column index
                    r, c = numpy.vstack(ndimage.center_of_mass(csv_to_matrix, numpy.arange(nlabels) + 1)).T
                    # add row index as first element of the pair
                    list005[i].append(r)
                    # add column index as second element of the pair
                    list005[i+1].append(c)
                dict005[file] = list005 

            elif val == 0.1:
                # Relabels the matrix True or False based on the >= condition, val=0.1 being the second cut-off
                blobs = csv_to_matrix >= val
                # Creates a few labels and records how many of them there are (nlabels)
                labels, nlabels = ndimage.label(blobs)
                # Empty list to store the coordinates row,column of the center of mass of each region
                list01 = []

                # loop through the nlabels identified
                for i in range(0, nlabels+1):
                    # compute row, column index
                    r, c = numpy.vstack(ndimage.center_of_mass(csv_to_matrix, numpy.arange(nlabels) + 1)).T
                    # add row index as first element of the pair
                    list01[i].append(r)
                    # add column index as second element of the pair
                    list01[i+1].append(c)
                dict01[file] = list01

            elif val == 0.2:
                # Relabels the matrix True or False based on the >= condition, val=0.2 being the third cut-off
                blobs = csv_to_matrix >= val
                # Creates a few labels and records how many of them there are (nlabels)
                labels, nlabels = ndimage.label(blobs)
                # Empty list to store the coordinates row,column of the center of mass of each region
                list02 = []
                # loop through the nlabels identified
                for i in range(0, nlabels+1):
                    # compute row, column index
                    r, c = numpy.vstack(ndimage.center_of_mass(csv_to_matrix, labels, numpy.arange(nlabels) + 1)).T
                    # add row index as first element of the pair
                    list02[i].append(r)
                    # add column index as second element of the pair
                    list02[i+1].append(c)
                dict02[file] = list02
```

Comment: You can set the values of dictionary items to almost anything, and you can assign them at will.  But check the definition of `OrderedDict` to see how reassignment affects the order, if at all.

Comment: Well, I am not aware of any reassignment of any kind in my code. The for block is meant to loop through my 100 matrices, and each new matrix you get a new key of the kind `matrix n` and a new list as value. Therefore, I failed to understand why you pointed the order thing out...

Comment: A side note: you can always invoke Python interactively and see what works and how. E.g. `print {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4, 5, 6]}`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I use this to do some debugging. Which means all the time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a new list every time, retrieve any existing list and append to it.

An easy way to do that is to use a `defaultdict` instead of an `OrderedDict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
d['somefile.csv'].extend([3, 4])
print(d)
# defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'somefile.csv': [3, 4]})
d['somefile.csv']
# [3, 4]
```